# Profile Native and Java memory in Android

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, profile

I am using the Android Monitor to profile an apps ram usage (for statistical purposes). However, the app is linked with a native librar written in C. When I allocate memory in the native code this is not seen in the Android memory monitor.

How can i profile both the allocated Java RAM together with the RAM allocated in the native code over time?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28144912/2214674 adb shell dumpsys meminfo <package_name>

Comment: Yes, however that gives me a snapshot of the memory. I would like to measure it over time.